# Why does OSX/Cocoa dock icon revert to default before going away?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, cross-platform

I'm working on wrapping some Cocoa functionality in an Objective-C library that will be called from a cross-platform C library.  One of my goals is to provide someone who does development in C on Linux with the ability to deploy to OSX without having to get into XCode, nib files, etc.  I want them to be able to compile and link their code on OSX using the command line tools, and end up with a regular resizeable main window with the usual buttons and so on, an application menu and a dock icon that looks and behaves as expected, etc.

I'm working on OSX 10.8.5.  I have XCode 5.0 installed.  Here's my `gcc --version` output:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I've figured out how to present a main window, how to set up the application menu, and various other things, programmatically, without using XCode or any nib or plist, but I've run into a problem with the dock icon.

I set a custom dock icon image by calling:

```
[NSApp setApplicationIconImage:dockImage];
```

When the user quits the app, the dock icon image reverts to something else (some kind of default application icon or view), briefly, before going away.  How can I prevent that from happening without using XCode to create a nib or a plist?

I've tried setting the activation policy of `NSApp` to prohibitted in the app delegate's `applicationShouldTerminate` method, to try to hide the dock icon before this switch back occurs.  That didn't help, it does hide the window and the dock icon, but the dock icon still switches back to the default icon, briefly, as part of the process of hiding.  I confirmed this by returning `NSTerminateLator`, and confirming that setting the activation policy to prohibited does cause the dock and the icon to hide even though the app is not terminating, and not setting it leaves it unhidden.

I've tried subclassing `NSApplication` and overriding the `setApplicationIconImage` call.  I have confirmed that it is being called a second time, by something other than my code (well, or not directly by my code, anyway), just before the program exits.  I've tried preventing the second call to it from working by calling the super function the first time, but not the second time, and I've confirmed that code in that function can prevent my code from changing the application icon, but that didn't fix the problem.  It still happens anyway, somehow.

I've also tried removing the application badge, like this:

```
[[window dockTile] setShowsApplicationBadge: NO];
```

just in case it was something to do with that, but that didn't work.  The docs say that app badges are no longer relevant as of 10.6, but I was grasping at straws.

Being stumped on the programmatic front, I'm now trying to find out how to package an .app from scratch,without using XCode, and see if maybe I can create a plist from scratch that has a reference to application image in it.  But a programmatic solution would be preferable, as I'd really like to minimize what goes into the OSX-specific packaging of a deployment.

Another possibility might be to use XCode once, to produce a very generic, bare-bones .app that my deployment scripts copy and alter.

Please don't shoot my question down as being "too broad" or "not constructive" or something like that.  I realize I'm reinventing wheels that already exist in various forms, but there's no law against trying to build a better mouse trap, or just a different or even a worse one, for that matter.  I realize I'm trying to fix a problem that a lot of people would consider inconsequential, but XCode-produced apps don't have this problem, and I really don't want the tools I'm creating to produce any user-visible artifacts like that.  I'm not intending to diss Apple's tool chain or invite debate about whether or not what I'm pursuing should be pursued.  I have a specific, technical problem that I'm looking for solution to that is within the constraints of my goals.

Comment: Just FYI, you might find this interesting: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html

Comment: I saw that some time back, that's pretty neat.  Still works, three years later, too.  I see it produces the same default icon that my custom one is reverting to on terminate.